# ¿Cómo imprimir una tabla de suma c#?

Tags: c#, .net, datatables, consola

Necesito hacer un programa el cual imprima por pantalla una tabla de suma, al momento que se ingrese un número, por ejemplo si se ingresa el número 3 imprima la tabla como está en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo una estructura más o menos como esta:

```
        int[,] suma = new int[5,5];
        int n;
        Console.Write("Ingrese un numero: ");
        n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int r=0; r < 5; r++)
        {
            for (int c=0; c <5; c++)
            {

            }
        }
```

Después de aquí no sé como estructurar el código para imprimir la tabla y sumar, apreciaría mucho de su ayuda, gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Introduce el indice de la matriz: ");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();

            int matriz;
            bool isNumeric = int.TryParse(input, out matriz);

            if (isNumeric)
            {
                List<int> lista = new List<int>() { };

                for (int i = 0; i <= matriz; i++)
                {
                    lista.Add(i);
                }


                //Escribe cabecera.
                Console.WriteLine(" + | " + String.Join(" ", lista.ToArray()));

                //Escribe separador de cabecera.
                //Enumerable.Repeat("-", 1 + listaX.Count*3) --> Repite el 
                //caracter '-' 3 veces por cada numero de la cabecera + 1 por la 
                //barra separadora
                Console.WriteLine(String.Concat(
                    Enumerable.Repeat("-", 1 + lista.Count * 3)));

                //Recorre la lista, realiza la suma y las muestra cada linea.
                for (int y = 0; y < lista.Count; y++)
                {
                    //Escribe los números de la lista a sumar.
                    Console.Write(" " + lista[y] + " | ");

                    for (int x = 0; x < lista.Count; x++)
                    {
                        Console.Write(lista[y] + lista[x] + " ");
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }            

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Resultado:

[image: Resultado]

La lógica la tienes, ahora solo faltaría cuadrar bien la cuadrícula, que está hecha un poco a ojo...

Answer (score 1):

Espero que esto pueda ayudarte, lo acabo de hacer. El resultado que muestra es este:

[image: resultado]

```
    using System;

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.Write("Ingrese un numero: ");
            int number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            for (int r=0; r <= number; r++)
            {
                for (int c=0; c <= number ; c++)
                {
                    Console.Write(r+c);
                }
                Console.Write("\n");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Creo que ni has entendido la pregunta ni sabes lo que estas haciendo. Los limites de la matriz tanto vertical como horizontal tiene que ser numero+1 (porque contamos el 0). En el resultado que pones introduces un 3 y el limite horizontal es 4 y el vertical 2 ?